# NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for #<Class:0xa3b9e1c> rails rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task

I am having this error when I am running a rake task. The rake used to run correctly before.

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for #<Class:0xa3b9e1c>
/home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-    
4.1.6/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
/home/munam/projects/ror/tftus/api/lib/data_providers/data_provider.rb:3:in `initialize'
/home/munam/projects/ror/tftus/api/lib/tasks/data_providers.rake:33:in `new'
/home/munam/projects/ror/tftus/api/lib/tasks/data_providers.rake:33:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => player:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My rake task:

```
require 'data_providers/providers'

# Affiliation Rake
namespace :affiliation do
  desc "Create Affiliations"
  task :create => :environment do
    AffiliationDataProvider.new.create
  end

  desc "Update Affiliations"
  task :update => :environment do
    AffiliationDataProvider.new.update
 end
end
```

Similarly there are other rake task in the same file which ran successfully before but not now.

This is what I get with trace

```
    ** Invoke affiliation:update (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment (first_time)
    ** Execute environment
    ** Execute affiliation:update
    rake aborted!
    NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for #<Class:0xa6aae3c>
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
    /home/munam/projects/ror/tftus/dynastyowner-api/lib/data_providers/affiliation.rb:19:in `update'
    /home/munam/projects/ror/tftus/dynastyowner-api/lib/tasks/data_providers.rake:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /home/munam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin/rake:23:in `load'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    /home/munam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
    Tasks: TOP => affiliation:update
```

Comment: add `--trace` at the end while running rake task to get more clear detail about the error

Comment: http://railsguides.net/how-to-generate-rake-task/

Comment: The trace suggests that the problem is at `/api/lib/data_providers/data_provider.rb:3:in initialize'` rather than in your rake task itself.

Comment: What's the source of `affiliation.rb`?

Comment: @Shadwell    affiliation = Affiliation.get('my_key') changed to     affiliation = Affiliation.find_by_key('my_key') works but I need a permanent fix. Is there anything else I can do. I  can't change it but only use it. Why has this topped working suddenly. Some dependency problem or sth else,

Comment: Hard for me to say exactly what has caused it but you've obviously got different version of that api kicking around (the two traces you've posted are with different libraries I think) so it's almost certainly because code is in a state of change. If you can't change that code then it seems like you should be contacting whoever did to establish the reason for the change and more importantly why it is now failing for you.

Comment: Paste your model code here. I guess your model is inherited from ActiveRecord not ActiveResource

Comment: @railites

class Affiliation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :players, dependent: :destroy
  
    # Validates the attributes when create and update
  validates :key, :abbreviation, :title,
    :presence => {:message => I18n.translate("messages.presence") },
    :uniqueness => {:message => I18n.translate("messages.uniquness")}

  validates :key, length: {in: 1..64}, if: :key?
  validates :title, length: {in: 1..256}, if: :title?
end

Comment: @railites When i replace ActiveRecord with ActiveResource I get this error
uninitialized constant ActiveResource

Comment: @techdreams http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html

Comment: @techdreams its ActiveResource::Base
One more thing your model says you are not using Other API for data. So you shouldn't add ActiveResource::Base and you can't use get.

Comment: And still if you wan to use ActiveResource::Base. Its mandatory to specify url from where you want to fetch data. For eg.     
self.site = "http://api.people.com:3000/"